# Having an error on discord loop, channel send

Tags: python, discord.py

So my problem is whenever I try to use loop, it give me an error called:
await channel.send('Nobody is online!')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

I've tried using that on @client.command() and that worked without a problem. Can you help me?

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 40)
async def t():
  channel = client.get_channel(908484216084385853)
               .
               .
               .
  if len(error_list) == len(names):
    await channel.send('Nobody is online!')
  else: 
    for i in range(len(friends_list)):
       await channel.send(friends_list[i].capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to rate limits. Instead of calling `client.get_channel` each time the function is called, you could assign it to a global variable.

For example:

```
async def on_ready():
  global channel
  channel = client.get_channel(908484216084385853)
  t.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds = 40)
async def t():
  
               .
               .
               .
  if len(error_list) == len(names):
    await channel.send('Nobody is online!')

  else: 
    for i in range(len(friends_list)):
       await channel.send(friends_list[i].capitalize())
```